# Connect to Kurento Room without stream

Tags: javascript, streaming, webrtc, kurento

I'm trying to connect to **Kurento Room** without stream. I'm creating
**localStream**

with this hash of params:

```
var localStream = kurento.Stream(room, {
    audio: false,
    video: false,
    data: false
});
...
...
localStream.init();
```

But anyway Kurento publishing my webcam to room, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit KurentoRoom.js

In that file, look for function Stream(kurento, local, room, options) and inside there is an init function (this.init = function() {...}).

This is where you can modify the constraints for the getUserMedia call.

Comment: Thank you, I just decide to do all logic on NodeJS without this java example. But thank you. Hope this will help somebody.